# Browser console input javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can I somehow track that the user entered something into the browser console?
I think it can be done, but I can't find anything

The matter is that I use a socket.io and the user can enter a command through the console that I would not like. Can this be somehow prevented?

Comment: “*the user can enter a command through the console that I would not like.*” Then you have a design flaw. Overriding the default functionality of the developer tools isn’t ever the answer.

Comment: Okay, what do you suggest?

Comment: Without knowing more about why you are apprehensive about users sending certain socket messages there’s not much I or anyone else here can suggest that will be actionable for you. Normally, your server would be able to implement enough logic to secure against anything like this - even if you were able to disable the developer console, there are an innumerable amount of WebSocket clients users could hypothetically use to lodge arbitrary messages to the socket outside the browser.

Comment: The user can safely fake the necessary data and then all checks on the server will be successful

Comment: Then you haven’t fully thought through a security architecture that sufficiently protects your backend.

Comment: Let's imagine that a message like 'userClickedButton' is sent without data. What checks should I make? I understand that this message won't hurt, but that's not what we're talking about.

Comment: Normally you would have to pass some sort of authentication information along with requests or socket messages that touch privileged data or services. Like I said, I can’t really advise on what would be a sufficient security architecture for your particular requirements/end goal without knowing, at a bare minimum, what you’re trying to protect, your threat model, and the overarching requirements to be implemented.

Comment: But after all, everything that is transmitted from the client can be changed using javascript. The user can find out this secret data and write it down when writing a message through the console